# Can I print an object of the class using printf()?

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I have some code like this:

```
class Point {
public:
    int x,y;
    Point() : x(1), y(1) {}
}
```

Can I print object of that class using `printf()`:

```
int main()
{
    Point point;
    printf("%o",point);
    return 0;
}
```

or I have to overload `operator<<` and use `std::cout`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Point const& p)
{
    os << p.x << "," << p.y;
    return os;
}
int main()
{
    Point point;
    std::cout << point;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remove the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: @IanAbbott Here you are!

Comment: What happened when you tried `printf`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Compilation was stopped, because expression `"%o"` is not valid. When I tried a valid one, like `"%d"`, there was an error **expects argument of type int**.

Comment: So there's the answer to your question.

Comment: another way is to add a `toString()` method, which you decide how to format your objects output.  Then call the method from the `printf` arguments eg `printf("my obj: %s\n",myObj.toString().c_str())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I print object of that class using `printf()`?

No. `printf` is not extensible in that sense.

Your best option is to overload `operator<<` between `std::ostream` and `Point`.

**PS** I suggest changing the argument type to `Point const&`.

Answer (score 0):

You can however, use a custom `print` function in your class, that would print your object the way you want:

```
...
void print() const {
  printf("[%d, %d]", x, y);
}
...

int main()
{
  Point point;
  point.print();
  return 0;
}
```

You can also use `fprintf` and a custom stream if you want to. This is not entirely an answer to your question, but seems to be useful in the described situation.

Comment: It's true, but using `std::cout` is more "natural", I guess.

Comment: @Nathiss, it depends. For example google style sheet forbids using streams and actually encourages to use `fprintf` instead.

**UPD:** uh.. oh... not any more. Now they slightly discourage using them, but do not forbid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to overload the operator otherwise , the `printf()` will get confused what to print of the object `point` as the class has two members.

Comment: Or you can declare another `getter() ` function which can print the values of the members.

Comment: How can I overload `printf()` function for that class?

Comment: `printf()` itself looks like overloading. Because, in this you can have `printf("%d", aDec)` and `printf("%f", aFloat)`. This looks a lot like function overloading , because we are using the same function name, but the function is accepting different parameter types – which is one of the ways we can overload functions.                                                 But for this class i would suggest you to do overloading <<

Comment: From what I know, `printf()` is C function. In standard C we can not overload any function.
We can print `int` and `float` variables, because in function `printf()` list of arguments is not specified. Because of this `printf()` can print any of basic types(int, float, double, char, bool) but not types specified by user.